# How to check if session is created or exixst in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, reference, codeigniter-2

This is my Controller to check if session exist or created

```
function guestcart(){
        if(!empty($session)){
            $seed = 132;
            $session = $this->session->userdata($seed);
            echo 'Session created';
        }  else {
            $this->session->userdata($seed); 
            echo 'Session exist ';

        }
    }
```

I am not able to bifurcate it I am new to codeigniter

Comment: I am not familiar with codeigniter but i guess that a session always exists (created with `session_start()`). By the way `$seed` is not set in your else statement.

Comment: Actually if $seed exists in my else then it will change the status of my current change I don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get session data you need to do, [$this->session->userdata('item')](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html), and check for its value, change it to:

```
function guestcart(){        
    $session = $this->session->userdata('seed_key');
    if(!empty($session)){            
        echo 'Session exist ';        
    }  else {     
        $seed = 132;   
        //set the session data    
        $session = $this->session->set_userdata('seed_key', $seed);
        echo 'Session created';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function guestcart(){
    $seed = 132;
    if(!empty($this->session->userdata($seed))){
        $session = $this->session->userdata($seed);
        echo 'Session created';
    }  else {
        $this->session->userdata($seed); 
        echo 'Session exist ';

    }
}
```